# Find values in a table with multiple data types and set them to NA or NaN

Tags: matlab, datatable, nan

I have a table (which I've called 'T' in this question) that is approx 105 x 10, with columns 2 & 3 containing strings, and all the rest containing numbers.
In columns 5 through 10 (which only contain numbers), I  have some values of 999 interspersed in the data that I want to set to NA or NaN. 
How can I do this? 
I've tried:

```
idx = T{:,5:10} == 999;
T{idx} = NaN;
T(ismissing(T,{999})) = NaN;
T{T==999}=NaN;
T(T{:,5:10}==999,:) = NaN;
```

The table data looks like this:

```
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial1'    0   -0.354977112125573  -0.342962246562734  999 999 999 999
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial1'    1   -0.185281358489472  0.196843601863376   0.191455534789190   0.191455534789190   0.196337466839364   0.239420563280515
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial1'    1   0.393217912708115   0.301686005068917   -0.167798347008035  -0.167798347008035  -0.107991484625157  0.108461970332887
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial1'    1   -0.145362442084958  -0.327523065746791  0.184717880799754   0.184717880799754   0.0848972787264908  0.166202231586311
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial2'    1   -0.309966518338289  -1.67389513513988   0.186656639405178   0.186656639405178   -0.0898354852721748 -0.232764706067819
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial2'    1   -0.0677751233445754 0.131643384129556   0.320810761759298   0.320810761759298   0.244546397660921   0.277629762491316
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial2'    1   -0.180564795679273  0.101929692518556   -0.134486855393823  -0.134486855393823  -1.61383942825616   0.100825254423938
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial3'    0   999 999 999 999 999 999
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial3'    1   -0.281085702707834  -0.0950243910429598 -0.0856708961622575 -0.0856708961622575 -0.221969474699963  -0.158533022159099
1   'LevelTwo'  'Trial4'    1   -1.01621209202249   -1.05630974785680   -0.128439670451306  -0.128439670451306  0.216852995526501   0.154914119245274
10  'LevelTwo'  'Trial10'   0   -2.60256948228157   -2.21021399689544   -0.513562238953105  -0.513562238953105  -0.918985308726539  -1.11565199530760
10  'LevelTwo'  'Trial11'   0   0.638560227147980   -0.660529540036614  -0.0354971842584826 -0.0354971842584826 999 999
```

Comment: sure, changed to 'T'. I understand a 'table' as being  a matlab data type called 'table', as opposed to a cell, array, struct etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code does exactly what I need.

```
standardizeMissing(T,999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a matrix of logical indices which you want to use to index into a matrix-like section of your table. However the only logical indexing supported by *tables* is *vectors* of logical indices referencing which rows *or* columns to pick. A logical vector on the row side of the index chooses the rows that are referenced for all referenced columns, and vice versa. It has to be this way because of the ambiguity that would arise from possible mixed data types that could be referenced by each element of the index.

You can stick with logical indexing if you work with the subset of the table that is numeric as a separate numeric array:

```
numbers = T{:,5:10};
numbers(numbers == 999) = NaN;
T{:,5:10} = numbers;
```

Or you can work column by column to deal in the table directly, with one logical vector to index rows at a time:

```
for ii = 5:10
    T{T{:,ii} == 999,ii} = NaN;
end
```